# Generate a String object from a List of code point integers?

Tags: java, string, unicode, codepoint

If I have a `List< Integer >` whose integer values are Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepoint) numbers. How do I construct a `String` object of characters determined by those code points?

For example:

```
List < Integer > codePoints = List.of( 100, 111, 103, 128054 ) ;
```

… or:

```
List < Integer > codePoints = "cat".codePoints().boxed().toList();
```

How do I get another `String` object with value `cat` from `codePoints`?

Comment: Good question! Just because you have used, `Stream#toList`, which is available from Java-16, it will be useful to the readers if the question is tagged to Java-16 as well.

Answer (score 4):

`String` [has a constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(int%5B%5D,int,int)) that takes an array of `int` code point numbers.

```
int[] ints = codePoints.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
String string = new String(ints, 0, ints.length);
```

Converts `List` -> `Stream` -> `IntStream` -> `int[]` -> `String`

Answer (score 1):

## `List` ➠ `Stream` ➠ `StringBuilder` ➠ `String`

One solution is to convert your `List` into a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html). Then collect the elements of that stream into a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). The `StringBuilder` class offers an [`appendCodePoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#appendCodePoint(int)) method specifically to accommodate code point integer numbers. When the mutable `StringBuilder` is complete, convert to an immutable `String`.

```
String output = codePoints.stream().collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append ).toString();
```

Or different formatting:

```java
String output = 
        codePoints
                .stream()
                .collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append )
                .toString();
```

Here is some example code.

```java
String input = "dog" ;
List < Integer > codePoints = input.codePoints().boxed().collect( Collectors.toList() );  // In Java 16+, replace the last part with simply `.toList()`.
String output = 
        codePoints
                .stream()
                .collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append )
                .toString();
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/rNtYoT).

> input: dog
>
> codePoints: [100, 111, 103, 128054]
>
> output: dog

To understand how that code with `StringBuilder` method references works, see [*Java 8 Int Stream collect with StringBuilder*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40962922/642706).

We could make a utility method of this code, for convenience. For safety, we could add a call to `.filter` to skip [any invalid code point](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isValidCodePoint(int)) number (either negative or beyond `Character.MAX_CODE_POINT`).

```java
public static final String listOfCodePointsToString( List< Integer > codePoints )
{
    String output = 
            codePoints
                    .stream()
                    .filter( codePoint -> Character.isValidCodePoint​( codePoint ) )
                    .collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append )
                    .toString();
    return output ;
}
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/rNtYoT).

Comment: _your_ - Didn't you mean _my_ there? I must be missing something.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I don't know what you mean.

Comment: You're answering your own question.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Yes, I am answering my own Question in the second-person so as to not distract the reader. The fact that I wrote both Question and Answer is irrelevant. I don't know why you would care.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers are fine, but there is also a simple "old fashioned" approach that doesn't require the use of functional interfaces or streams. Here's minimal and complete sample code:

```
package cp2string;

import java.util.List;

public class CP2String {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List< Integer> codePoints = List.of(100, -999, 111, 103, 128054);
        Character BLACK_VERTICAL_RECTANGLE = '\u25AE';
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int cp : codePoints) {
            sb.append(Character.toString(Character.isValidCodePoint(cp) ? cp : BLACK_VERTICAL_RECTANGLE));
        }
        System.out.println("sb=" + sb.toString());
    }
}
```

When the code is run this is the output:

> sb=d▮og

Notes:

- The black rectangle in the output represents an invalid code point that was deliberately included in the sample data.
- JDK 11 or later is required for the static method  `Character.toString​(int codePoint)`.
- A font change may be needed to properly render the output. I used **Segoe UI Symbol**.
- Obviously using a stream based approach is the way to go if parallel operations are a consideration, but for scenarios where performance and scalability are not concerns, a simple approach is arguably just as good.