# replacing all cases of ISO Control characters in a string with "CTRL"

Tags: java

```
 static String clean(String identifier) {
    String firstString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < identifier.length(); i++)
        if (Character.isISOControl(identifier.charAt(i))){
            firstString = identifier.replaceAll(identifier.charAt(i), 
                          "CTRL");
         }
            
        return firstString;
}
```

The logic behind the code above is to replace all instances of ISO Control characters in the string 'identifier' with "CTRL". I'm however faced with this error: "char cannot be converted to java.lang.String"

Can someone help me to solve and improve my code to produce the right output?

Comment: `return identifier.replaceAll("\\p{Cc}", "");` is all you need.  `Cc` is a [Unicode general category](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values) and `\\p` is [how regular expressions refer to Unicode categories](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ucc).

Answer (score 1):

[String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) expects a String as parameter, *but* it has to be a regular expression. Use [String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char)) instead.

EDIT: I haven't seen that you want to replace a character by some string. In that case, you can use this version of [String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) but you need to convert the character to a String, e. g. by using [Character.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(char)).

**Update**

Example:

```
String text = "AB\003DE";
text = text.replace(Character.toString('\003'), "CTRL");
System.out.println(text);
// gives: ABCTRLDE
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just tried your suggestion and this the new error format i'm present with: " method java.lang.String.replace(char,char) is not applicable (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to char)"

Comment: "ABC".replace(Character.toString('A'), "Hello") will result in "HelloBC".

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks! I perceive your approach to be for some instances of the iso control characters (meaning hard coding the iso control characters in this case), and if that is so, I find it difficult to apply in the context of the challenge I'm solving thus generalizing everything and calling on the isISOControl method to determine whether a character is one before replacing.

Comment: It's following your approach, you can do something like Character.toString(identifier.charAt(i)), of course. You can also use replaceAll with some regular expression, e. g. "AB\003DE".replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "CTRL") will replace any control character by CTRL in a single step.

Comment: it's however failing a test case like: "@Test
public void ctrl() {
    assertThat(SqueakyClean.clean("my\0\r\u007FId")).isEqualTo("myCTRLCTRLCTRLId");
}"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246949/discussion-between-user16790478-and-mihe).

Answer (score 0):

## Code points, and *Control Picture* characters

I can add two points:

- The `char` type is essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. Best to use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integers when working with individual characters.
- Unicode defines characters for display as placeholders for control characters. See [*Control Pictures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters#Control_pictures) section of one Wikipedia page, and see another page, [*Control Pictures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Pictures).

For example, the NULL character at code point 0 decimal has a matching [SYMBOL FOR NULL](https://unicodeplus.com/U+2400) character at 9,216 decimal: `␀`. To see all the Control Picture characters, use [this PDF](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf) section of the Unicode standard specification.

Get an array of the code point integers representing each of the characters in your string.

```
int[] codePoints = myString.codePoints().toArray() ;
```

Loop those code points. Replace those of interest.

Here is some untested code.

```java
int[] replacedCodePoints = new int[ codePoints.length ] ;
int index = 0 ;
for ( int codePoint : codePoints )
{
    if( codePoint >= 0 && codePoint <= 32 ) // 32 is SPACE, so you may want to use 31 depending on your context.
    {
        replacedCodePoints[ index ] = codePoint + 9_216 ;  // 9,216 is the offset to the beginning of the Control Picture character range defined in Unicode.
    } else if ( codePoint == 127 )  // DEL character.
    {
        replacedCodePoints[ index ] = 9_249 ;
    } else  // Any other character, we keep as-is, no replacement.
    {
        replacedCodePoints[ index ] = codePoint ;
    }
    i ++ ;  // Set up the next loop.
}
```

Convert code points back into text. Use `StringBuilder#appendCodePoint` to build up the characters of text. You can use the following stream-based code as boilerplate. For explanation, see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40962922/642706).

```java
String result = 
    Arrays
        .stream( replacedCodePoints )
        .collect( StringBuilder::new , StringBuilder::appendCodePoint , StringBuilder::append )
        .toString();
```